# JQuery-Mobile expand/collapse on icon click?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Does anybody knows how to implement expand/collapse only on icon click in collapsibe div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found following way:

```
...
                collapsibleHeading.find(".ui-icon").bind("click", function (event) {
                    var type = collapsibleHeading.is(".ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed") ?
                                                                                "expand" :                "collapse";

                    collapsible.trigger(type);

                    event.preventDefault();
                });
```

If you need more details let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

Try jQM's [Collapsible content](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible.html). All you need to to is add `data-role="collapsible"` to a div, e.g.:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
   <h3>I'm a header</h3>
   <p>
      I'm the collapsible content. 
      By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean on on icon click. Not div header click.